# LINQ to SQL DataContext Is Not Updating ConnectionString

Tags: c#, sql, database, linq, layer

I am working on a C# .NET application that uses LINQ to SQL for database access.  Unfortunately, I have spent the past 4 hours trying to get the application to work on my home network.  I have brought the application home before for development without issues and transferred the changes back to work.  However, this evening I continued to have issues with database access and noticed that the connection string in my DAO was referencing my work ComputerName/Instance.  I searched my entire solutions for my work PC Name (i.e. BEN-Laptop) and I also used Windows advanced search options to search my entire directory.  However, I could not find any references to my work PC.  When I brought the application home to work on I changed all connection string values from my work pc to my home pc and I do not understand why the connection string in the DAO is somehow still referencing my work PC and SQL instance.  Is this information cached somewhere because I am at a loss.

Comment: To be more specific, the connection properties that I changed were primarily in the app.config and dbml file.  I merely do not understand why my application is still trying to find the database on my work PC when I have used every search mechanism possible to change references from my work PC (i.e. Ben-Laptop to Major-HomePC).  The only thing I can think of is that this information is cached somewhere outside of my project but, I am fairly new to .NET development and feel like I have exhausted my efforts.  Please offer suggestions.  I appreciated it.

Comment: Try to `Clean` your project and do a `ReBuild`. Secondly the connection string is only read from `app.config`, can you tell me where did you find it in `dbml` file. The changes in app.config only reflects when you restart the application. What is  the type of your  application winform, console or window service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open up your dbml file in design view and view the properties (F4) you should find a ConnectionString property. When you expand the list of available connection strings it should tell you the source of each string. It's most likely coming from the settings file. (~\Properties\Settings.settings)

Ideally when you create a data context you should use the constructor which takes a connection string and you will know exactly where it's coming from.

```
using(var dc = new TestDataContext(connectionString))
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with my database connection string in the DataContext was actually the result of my colleague re-structuring the solution.  In short, the windows application is in one project and the database logic is compiled as a DLL in another project.  The windows application was referring to an old version of the DLL that apparently had my work settings for the connection string.  I merely had to change the reference in my project to the correct DLL and everything worked fine.  That also explains why I could not find any references to my work PC in the solution because I presume that the settings are compiled into the DLL file.  Attempting to debug my Database DLL project helped lead to this discovery.  After setting several break points in my base DAO and Repository classes and finding the IDE was bypassing breakpoints, it prompted me to check the references.

Comment: Now, I am passing the connection string into my constructors as suggested above.

Comment: For future reference, you should try using project references rather than referencing the .dll output of a project.

Answer (score 1):

first : just mention the new connection string that should look like this

```
string pp = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\AdventureWorks2012_Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
```

second :

```
DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext(pp);
```

third:
      do the changes on the instances of the table classs

fourth :

```
 dc.Persons.InsertOnSubmit(person);
        dc.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: Another answer where it's clear you don't understand the question

Answer (score 1):

Your `DataContext()` constructor is missing the string that tells it the path of your actual data base.